# Is my attempt at solving $y'=\frac{y}x+\left(1-\frac1x\right)$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given the following first-order, linear differential equation, 
>   $$y'=\dfrac{y}x+\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)$$
>   find the constant $c$ such that $y(-1)=0$ and say for which $\alpha$ there are solutions for which $y(0)=\alpha$

**My attempt**

The equation is of the form $y'(x)=a(x)y(x)+b(x)$ where $a(x)=1/x$ and $b(x)= \left(1-\frac1x\right)$. Both $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are continuous in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$. Then the solution is:

$$\begin{align}y(x)&=e^{\int1/x \ \mathrm dx}\left[\int e^{-\int1/x \ \mathrm dx}\left(1-\frac1x\right)\mathrm d x +c\right]\\
&=e^{\log|x|}\left[\int e^{-\log|x|}\left(1-\frac1x\right)\mathrm d x +c\right]\\
&=|x|\left[\int\left(\frac{1}{|x|}-\frac{1}{|x|}\frac1x\right)\mathrm d x +c\right]\\
&=|x|\log|x|+c|x|-|x|\int\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\frac1x\right)\mathrm d x\tag1\end{align}$$

I then split the equation in $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ and I got:

$$\begin{cases}x>0\\ x\log x+cx+1 \end{cases}\cup \begin{cases}x<0\\ -x\log (-x)+cx+1 \end{cases}$$
Then, if $y(-1)=0 \implies 1\log(1)-c+1=0\implies c=1$

I think there are no values of $\alpha$ for which $y(0)=\alpha$ because $y(x)$ is not defined in $x=0$

**EDIT: (Thanks to Winther and Isham)**

$(1)$ should have been: $$|x|\operatorname{sign}x\log|x|+c|x|-|x|\int\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\frac1x\right)\mathrm d x$$

Then $$y(x)=x\log|x|+cx+1$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}y(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}y(x)=1\implies \alpha=1?$$

Comment: Yes your expression are not defined for $x = 0$, but the *limit* $x\to 0$ exists. A solution on the domain $\mathbb{R}$ has to be continuous at $0$ so the value of $y(0)$ has to be equal to this limit.

Comment: btw I find that the solution for $x<0$ is $x\log(-x) + cx + 1$ so that we can express $y(x) = x \log|x| + cx + 1$.

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: I edited the question to correct my error in the solution for $x<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats correct to me...Got the same result too
$$y'=\dfrac{y}x+\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)$$
$$xy'=y+x\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)$$
$$\frac  {xy'-y}{x^2}=\frac 1x\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)$$
$$(\frac yx)'=\frac 1x\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)$$
Integrate
$$y(x)=x\int \frac 1x\left(1-\dfrac1x\right)dx +Kx$$
$$y(x)=x \ln|x|+1+Kx$$
$$y(-1)=0 \implies K=1 \implies y(x)=x \ln|x|+1+x$$

Comment: And for which $α$ are there solutions for which $y(0)=α$?